# Flex 4.0: Common function across modules

Tags: apache-flex, module, flex4

We are working on a project where we have multiple modules- all these share a common set of functions like rounding, string parsing etc.

Currently, we have added these functions into the parent container (which calls these modules) and use them in the respective modules. Likewise, if we have to share variables between modules, we add them to the parent module- so it becomes shareable across.

Is this the right approach- both from a performance and structure perspective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking about Singletons.

Check my answer here please : [use actionscript file in flex library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198245/use-actionscript-file-in-flex-library/6198520#6198520)

Comment: If they're utility functions, you don't even need a singleton, they can just be static classes kinda like when you use StringUtil or ObjectUtil.

Answer (score 3):

You should create a runtime shared library project (RSL) and have some classes with static functions. That is how we do it. This can be shared between all of the modules, also you can then use that RSL for any future projects as well.